# How to format first 7 rows in this txt file using Regex

Tags: regex

I have a text file with data formatted  as below. Figured out how to format the second part of the file to format it for upload into a db table. Hitting a wall trying to get the just the first 7 lines to format in the same way.

If it wasn't obvious, I'm trying to get it pipe delimited with the exact same number of columns, so I can easily upload it to the db.

```
Year: 2019 Period: 03
Office: NY
Dept: Sales
Acct: 111222333
SubAcct: 11122234-8
blahblahblahblahblahblahblah
Status: Pending
1000
AAAAAAAAAA
100,000.00
2000
BBBBBBBBBB
200,000.00
3000
CCCCCCCCCC
300,000.00
4000
DDDDDDDDDD
400,000.00
```

some kind folks answered my question about the bottom part, using the following code I can format that to look like so -

```
(.*)\r?\n(.*)\r?\n(.*)(?:\r?\n|$)

substitute with |||||||$1|$2|$3\n

|||||||1000|AAAAAAAAAA|100,000.00
|||||||2000|BBBBBBBBBB|200,000.00
|||||||3000|CCCCCCCCCC|300,000.00
|||||||4000|DDDDDDDDDD|400,000.00
```

just need help formatting the top part - to look like this, so the entire file matches with the exact same number of columns.

```
Year: 2019|Period: 03|Office: NY|Dept: Sales|Acct: 111222333|SubAcct: 11122234-8|blahblahblahblahblahblahblah|Status: Pending|||
```

I'm ok with having multiple passes on the file to get the desired end result.

Answer (score 1):

I've helped you on your previous question, so I will focus now on the first part of your file.

You can use this regex:

```
\n|\b(?=Period)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/YvEH5t/1)**

And use `|` as the replacement string

If you don't want the previous space before `Period`, then you can use:

```
\n|\s(?=Period)
```

Comment: Thank you Federico !! Couple of things if you can look at -
    1. How to apply this pattern only to the first 7 rows (because the rest of them are already formatted.)
    2. How to add 3 pipe symbols to the end of it (that way the entire txt file will have same no. of columns).

Thanks so much !